# what is conditional forwarder

Tags: domain-name-system

what is conditional forwarder ?

Answer (score 3):

It allows you to specify a specific DNS server for clients trying to resolve hosts in a specific domain.

see: http://msmvps.com/blogs/ad/archive/2008/09/05/how-to-configure-conditional-forwarders-in-windows-server-2008.aspx

So if you had a test internal environment with a DNS server and web server for testyourdomain.com, you could create a conditional forwarder on your main domain that would not go to root hints for that domain, but direct to the clients to your other test DNS server that would have records for testyourdomain.com